# Selecting from multiple tables with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
t1 (select these records)
-------------
id
offer_id
business_id

t2 (offer details)
-------------
id
offer_details
business_id


t3 (business details)
-------------
id
business_name
```

I need to select all records from t1 and add information from t2 and t3. Seems basic but I can't seem to be able to get it right -- must be the heat.

```
SELECT t2.offer_details, t3.business_name
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON (t1.offer_id = t2.id)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t1.business_id = t3.id)
```

Comment: seems right ... show a proper sample

Comment: Why you think it is wrong?

Comment: I'm getting results from businesses that are not in t1... and multiple repeats of the same offers.

Comment: You will get businesses that's not in t1 because of `LEFT JOIN`. Change to `JOIN` then you'll get only businesses in t1. Also change your main table in query from t2 to t1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
 SELECT t2.offer_details, t3.business_name
 FROM t1
 LEFT JOIN t1 ON (t1.offer_id = t2.id)
 LEFT JOIN t3 ON (t1.business_id = t3.id)
```

Your lead table is t1 and the join should be based  on this table

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
Select t2.offer_details, t3.business_name
From t1
Left Join t2 ON (t1.offer_id = t2.id)
Left Join t3 ON (t1.business_id = t3.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all records from t1, add `t1.*` on your select part. Assuming that all IDs in t1 exists in the other 2 tables

```
SELECT
    t1.*, t2.offer_details, t3.business_name
FROM
    t1
    JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.offer_id
    JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t1.business_id
```

Modify to `LEFT JOIN` if the IDs in t1 may be missing in t2 or t3.

Comment: t1 just contains IDs of records in other tables.

Comment: Then delete `t1.*`. You should get all the offer IDs and business IDs listed on t1.